# Process pool in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, volatility, yara

I am trying to get a `for` loop that will only execute a threaded volatility yara scan module based off a list of rules. One scan per rule per core. Basically it should take the current number of vol.py processes running and check against the core count and maximize the processes running.

However, when I run this it will spawn a volatility process for every rule and not just the max of 4 (based off my core count). Any help with the syntax here would be great.

Currently I have this:

```
count=$(ps aux | grep vol.py | wc -l)
cores=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l)
for x in $(cat $rules_path/rules.txt)
do
  if [ $count -lt $cores ]; then # we are under the limit
     echo $x
     vol.py -f /home/cuckoo/.cuckoo/storage/analyses/12/memory.dmp --profile=Win7SP1x64 yarascan --yara-file=$rules_path/allrules/$x --output=text --output-file=$out_dir/$x.log &>/home/$name/Desktop/error.txt & 
  else
     wait
  fi
done
```

Comment: I think you want `count` to be a current indication of the number of `vol.py` processes. But you only measure this once at the start. You'll want to do it again inside the loop.

Comment: Ah, okay. Do I place the variable inside the for statement or the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach could work, with something like:

```
cores=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l)
count=$(ps aux | grep vol.py | wc -l)
for x in $(cat $rules_path/rules.txt)
do
  if [ $count -lt $cores ]; then # we are under the limit
     echo $x
     vol.py -f /home/cuckoo/.cuckoo/storage/analyses/12/memory.dmp --profile=Win7SP1x64 yarascan --yara-file=$rules_path/allrules/$x --output=text --output-file=$out_dir/$x.log &>/home/$name/Desktop/error.txt & 
     count=$(ps aux | grep vol.py | wc -l)
  else
     wait -n
  fi
done
```

All I've changed is:

- recalculate `count` each time we add a process
- `wait -n` -- to just wait for one job to end

---

However there are simpler ways to achieve this. One is with `xargs --max-procs`:

```
cat $rules_path/rules.txt | xargs --max-procs="$cores" -n1 call_volatility
```

... where `call_volatility` is a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1
vol.py -f /home/cuckoo/.cuckoo/storage/analyses/12/memory.dmp \
     --profile=Win7SP1x64 yarascan \
     --yara-file=$rules_path/allrules/$x \
     --output=text \
     --output-file=$out_dir/$x.log \
     &>/home/$name/Desktop/error.txt
```

---

There is no guarantee with either approach that the processes will be evenly distributed between your cores.

Comment: Is there a way to pipe the stdout and stderr to a file? Not too sure how to use mkfifo with this loop...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, specifically. Perhaps it needs to go in a separate question. There's nothing in here that would prevent you from working with fifos.

Comment: I'll work with it a bit and see what I can come up with, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `sem` from GNU parallel:

```
for x in $(cat "$rules_path/rules.txt")
do
  sem -j +0 vol.py -f /home/cuckoo/.cuckoo/storage/analyses/12/memory.dmp \
      --profile=Win7SP1x64 yarascan --yara-file="$rules_path/allrules/$x" \
      --output=text --output-file="$out_dir/$x.log" \
         &> "/home/$name/Desktop/error.txt"
done
```

You don't have to count cores or manage processes. `sem` handles everything, and runs one process per core.